# Replacing dead master in Kubernetes 1.15 cluster with stacked control plane

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 3-master stacked control plane - so each master also has its own etcd instance running locally.  The problem I am trying solve is this: 
"If one master dies such that it cannot be restarted, how do I replace it?"

Currently, when I try to add the replacement master into the cluster, I get the following error while running `kubeadm join`:

```
[check-etcd] Checking that the etcd cluster is healthy
I0302 22:43:41.968068    9158 local.go:66] [etcd] Checking etcd cluster health
I0302 22:43:41.968089    9158 local.go:69] creating etcd client that connects to etcd pods
I0302 22:43:41.986715    9158 etcd.go:106] etcd endpoints read from pods: https://10.0.2.49:2379,https://10.0.225.90:2379,https://10.0.247.138:2379
error execution phase check-etcd: error syncing endpoints with etc: dial tcp 10.0.2.49:2379: connect: no route to host
```

The 10.0.2.49 node is the one that died.  These nodes are all running in an AWS AutoScaling group, so I don't have control over the addresses.

I have drained and deleted the dead master node using `kubectl drain` and `kubectl delete`; and I have used `etcdctl` to make sure the dead node was not in the member list.

Why is it still trying to connect to that node's etcd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the failed node was still listed in the ConfigMap.  Further investigation led me to the following thread, which discusses the same problem:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1300

The solution that worked for me was to edit the ConfigMap manually.

```
kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml > tmp-kubeadm-config.yaml
manually edit tmp-kubeadm-config.yaml to remove the old server
kubectl -n kube-system apply -f tmp-kubeadm-config.yaml
```

I believe updating the etcd member list is still necessary to ensure cluster stability, but it wasn't the full solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is still trying to connect to the member because etcd maintains a list of members in its store -- that's how it knows to vote on quorum decisions. I don't believe etcd is unique in that way -- most distributed key-value stores know their member list

[The fine manual](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.4.4/Documentation/demo.md#member) shows how to remove a dead member, but [it also warns](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.4.4/Documentation/faq.md#should-i-add-a-member-before-removing-an-unhealthy-member) to add a new member before removing unhealthy ones.

There is also a project [etcdadm](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/etcdadm#readme) that is designed to smooth over some of the rough edges about etcd cluster management, but I haven't used it to say what it is good at versus not